# Could not draw bounding box border in prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

How do i draw a border around bounding box with specific setting

```
bounding_box([175, starting_y - 190], :width => 30.mm, :height => 17.mm) do
  stroke_color 'FFFF00'
  dash 10, space: 4
  stroke_bounds
end
```

I would like to have border dotted for bottom alone, How will i have this?

I tried searching in stroke, stroke_bounds, bounding_box of prawn document, i could not find anything

Comment: Do you want just one dashed line, or 3 continuous lines and 1 dashed line?

Answer (score 1):

You could draw the lines separately :

```
require "prawn"

Prawn::Document.generate("bbox.pdf") do
  x = 175
  y = 200
  width = 100
  height = 50
  color = 'FFFF00'

  stroke do
    stroke_color color
    vertical_line   y, y+height, :at => x
    vertical_line   y, y+height, :at => x+width
    horizontal_line x, x+width,  :at => y+height
  end

  stroke do
    stroke_color color
    dash 10, space: 4
    horizontal_line x, x+width, :at => y
  end
end
```

It outputs

[image]